# Qt QGraphicsScene::setSceneRect() doesn't actually set the scene rect

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene

I've implemented a simple image viewer widget. It works fine, but when I'm trying to upload a picture and then replace it with a smaller one, it's not centered. I've done some little research and figured out that the problem is with the `sceneRect` in `QGraphicsScene`. So I've written some code to reset it every time before the image is uploaded. I've also put some `qDebug()` stuff between the lines just to be certain that it is really setting this rect to null. And unfortunately, it remains unchanged even after calling this `setSceneRect()` function. Here's some code to better understand my problem:

```
void function_which_uploads_and_show_images()
{
    QString file_path = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "title", "/", "*.jpg");
    this->image = QPixmap(file_path);
    this->scene->clear();
    this->scene->setSceneRect(QRectF()); //setting sceneRect to the null rect

    // here goes some code to scale the image if necessary

    this->scene->addPixmap(file_path);
}
```

My question is: **How I can reset the** `sceneRect`  **so every time I upload an image it will be centered?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not a very clean solution to this problem, but one can do the following to reset the scene rect:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
view->addScene(scene);
```

It works, but I'm almost sure that it could be achieved another way, so if you have a better answer to this problem, please post it here.

Comment: What about setting the sceneRect to the size of the final image (with position {0,0})?

Comment: It works only when I set the sceneRect at init time on `QGraphicsView`. It would be the solution but only if no more than one image is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're only providing partial code as to how the image is really getting centered "automagically" in the first place. You may want to look into something like a `QGraphicsLayout` to manage the positioning instead.

But to address the question, you could try setting the scene rect on the **view** instead. You probably would only need to do it once at init time.

From `QGraphicsView::sceneRect` doc:

> The scene rectangle defines the extent of the scene, and in the view's case, this means the area of the scene that you can navigate using the scroll bars.
>
> If unset, or if a null QRectF is set, this property has the same value as QGraphicsScene::sceneRect, and it changes with QGraphicsScene::sceneRect. Otherwise, the view's scene rect is unaffected by the scene.
>
> By default, this property contains a rectangle at the origin with zero width and height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately `QGraphicsLayout` works only with `QGraphicsWidget`. I tried setting the scene rect on the view at init time and before uploading the picture but it also didn't work.